# Como colorir aleatoriamente DIVs com um Array de cores em javascript?

Tags: javascript, array

Criei uma função que vai trocando cores (puxadas de um *array*) em determinados elementos da página (que também estão em *array*), porém ficou muito estranho, pois vai trocando as cores dos elementos um após o outro. Queria fazer algo diferente, como: Sortear o elemento e a cor que irão ser modificados. **Como eu adapto a minha função para fazer isso?**
Exemplo -> http://jsbin.com/citoq/1/watch?output

```
window.onload = function(){
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    var background = ["#f36", "#C3C", "#fc0", "#FC6", "#9C0"];
    cor=0;
    div=0;
    setInterval(function(){
            box.item(div).style.backgroundColor = background[cor];
            cor++; div++;
            if(cor>=background.length){
                cor=0;}
            if(div>=box.length){
                div=0;}
        },2000)
}
```

Comment: Tu queres que apareçam cores desse vetor de "aleatória"?

Comment: Isso, quero que tanto as cores, quantos os elementos sejam trocados aleatóriamente

Comment: Você pode conferir [aqui](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) sua resposta

Comment: Valeu @ErlonCharles!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Imagino que o que você queira seja isso:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    var background = ["#f36", "#C3C", "#fc0", "#FC6", "#9C0"];
    cor=0;
    div=0;
    setInterval(function(){
            cor = Math.floor(Math.random() * (background.length - 1));
            div = Math.floor(Math.random() * (background.length - 1));
            box.item(div).style.backgroundColor = background[cor];
        },2000)
}
```

Caso você não queira repetir as cores, é possível fazer o seguinte: (Lembrando que o mesmo pode ser feito para `div` também)

```
var coresQueNaoForam = [0,1,2,3,4];
window.onload = function(){
    var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
    var background = ["#f36", "#C3C", "#fc0", "#FC6", "#9C0"];
    cor=0;
    div=0;
    setInterval(function(){
            cor = Math.floor(Math.random() * (coresQueNaoForam.length - 1));
            div = Math.floor(Math.random() * (background.length - 1));
            box.item(div).style.backgroundColor = background[coresQueNaoForam.splice(cor,1)];
            if(coresQueNaoForam.length == 0){
              coresQueNaoForam = [0,1,2,3,4];
            }              
        },2000)
}
```

Comment: Exatamente @Felipe, valeu mesmo cara!

Answer (score 5):

Você pode usar [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

```
var arrCores = ['#f00', '#0f0', '#0ff'];

setInterval(function(){
    document.getElementById('divRandom').style.backgroundColor = arrCores[Math.round(Math.random()*(arrCoresSize-1))]
}, 500);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GatXT/)

### Cores que não se repetem

```
var arrCores = ['#f00', '#0f0', '#0ff'];
var arrCoresUsadas = [];

setInterval(function(){
    // Define cor aleatória
    var index = Math.round(Math.random() * (arrCores.length-1));
    document.getElementById('divRandom').style.backgroundColor = arrCores[index];

    // Marca cor como usada
    arrCoresUsadas.push(arrCores[index]);
    arrCores.splice(index, 1);

    // Todas as cores usadas, começa tudo de novo:
    if (arrCores.length === 0){
        arrCores = arrCoresUsadas;
        arrCoresUsadas = [];
    }
}, 500);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GatXT/1/)

---

Nesses casos, estou esperando que o array contenha elementos... Por preucação, poderia haver uns if's pra evitar erros, caso o arrays possam ser vazios por algum motivo.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Andre!

Answer (score 1):

## Resposta:

Você pode randomizar uma cor hexadecimal utilizando `Math.floor()` e `Math.random()` desta forma:

```
var corRandom = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
```

## Explicação:

Uma cor em hexadecimal deve inicar com o caráctere '#' por isso a concatenação, antes da geração da função randomica, calculando para obter um resultado de um hexadecimal e sendo convertido para String utilizando `toString()`.

**Você não deve, não precisa utilizar um Array para armazenar as cores, uma  vez que elas podem ser geradas.**

Seu código ficaria desta maneira utilizando este método citado acima:

```
var box = document.getElementsByClassName('box');
div=0;
setInterval(function(){
        box.item(div).style.backgroundColor = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
        div++;
        if(div>=box.length){
            div=0;
        }
    },2000);
```

## [Exemplo funcionando no JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8K92a/)

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda @Paulo! Muito útil

Comment: Não entendi o porque de não armazenar as cores pq elas podem ser geradas.. E se eu quero por exemplo, randomizar entre 5 cores pré-determinadas?

Comment: Bom, agora que você disse, eu li novamente o título da pergunta e ele realmente quer cores predeterminadas então não seria bem isso, porém é uma alternativa.. pelo menos foi útil.

Comment: SIm, de fato eu queria cores pré-determinadas @PauloRoberto para não ter perigo das cores não combinarem com o restante do layout, mas esse exemplo seu foi muito útil, não tinha ideia de que dava para fazer isso.