# Gerar vários números aleatórios sem repetição

Tags: javascript, números-aleatórios

Fiz algumas tentativas para fazer uma função que retornasse números aleatórios que não se repetissem, eu fiz algumas tentativas mas nenhuma teve sucesso, se puderem me mostrar uma função que faça isso agradeço.

Comment: Que formato procura nos números? decimais ou inteiros? Entre que intervalo?

Comment: Números inteiros, o intervalo seria entre 1 e 1000.

Comment: Júnior a minha resposta tinha um bug. Com o aviso do Bacco corrigí. Melhor usar o novo código.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5848

Answer (score 17, accepted):

A solução que me ocorre é criar uma array e adicionar-lhe os valores já criados/sorteados, e procurar na array se o valor já existe antes de exportar um novo.

Esta solução permite sortear valores um a um assim como sorteá-los todos de uma vez.

```
var sorteados = [];
var valorMaximo = 1000;

function criarUnico() {
    if (sorteados.length == valorMaximo) {
        if (confirm('Já não há mais! Quer recomeçar?')) sorteados = [];
        else return;
    }
    var sugestao = Math.ceil(Math.random() * valorMaximo); // Escolher um numero ao acaso
    while (sorteados.indexOf(sugestao) >= 0) {  // Enquanto o numero já existir, escolher outro
        sugestao = Math.ceil(Math.random() * valorMaximo);
    }
    sorteados.push(sugestao); // adicionar este numero à array de numeros sorteados para futura referência
    return sugestao; // devolver o numero único
}
```

Assim, para sortear um numero é só usar:

```
criarUnico(); // que retorna um valor único
```

### [Exemplo](http://jsfiddle.net/Q58ER/1/)

Comment: Uma sugestão... será que não seria melhor diminuir a abrangência do random em medida que os números vão sendo sorteados? desta forma evita que seja randomizado várias vezes numeros já sorteados e demorar pra achar números que ainda não foram, quando houver já muitos números sorteados.

Comment: Apenas lembrar que essa função entra em loop infinito depois que todos os números 0..1000 tiverem sido sorteados. (@PauloRoberto assim não fica uniforme)

Comment: o que quer dizer com "uniforme" ? @GuilhermeBernal. A propósito eu concordo com você mas se a função insistir em retornar valores que já existem vai ser uma queda imensa na performance.

Comment: @PauloRoberto que se você limitar a abrangência depois, vai impedir que alguns valores saiam. Uniforme no sentido de que qualquer valor não sorteado tenha a mesma probabilidade de sair.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal, obrigado pela indicação. Eu tinha adicionado no jsFiddle uma solução para recomeçar a contagem. Agora juntei também no código da resposta.

Comment: @GuilhermeBernal você não me entendeu. é claro que vai ter a mesma probabilidade, você vai estar randomizando entre os números que ainda não foram sorteados, que no caso, vão ser os únicos que irão proceder com o código. Isso pouparia performance e resultaria no mesmo resultado com a mesma probabilidade.

Comment: @PauloRoberto nesse caso não tem uma boa forma de balancear o range para excluir valores selecionados. De uma forma ou de outra haverá muitos valores já selecionados dentro do range. Mas sim, é uma otimização aceitável, embora mínima (imagine que os números 1 e 1000 foram sorteados por último).

Comment: É, eu não sei como poderia ser feito, porém seria uma boa pra performance.

Comment: @PauloRoberto Tentei fazer algo como o sugerido (reduzir a abrangência do random a cada sorteio), mapeando os números já sorteados àqueles não sorteados e removidos do intervalo, mas a performance ficou pior... Exceto talvez por alguns casos degenerados (ex.: dentre 1000000 escolher 999999), esse método é de fato o que tem o melhor desempenho. [Teste comparativo no jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/sorteio-sem-repeti-o).

Comment: Não tenho certeza mas acho que o método has() do Set tem mais performance que o indexOf() do Array, se o objetivo é tentar otimizar pode ser um começo  https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 21):

Primeiro, gere uma lista ordenada, neste exemplo de 1 a 1000:

```
var maximo = 1000;

var i, arr = [];
for (i = 0; i < maximo; i++) {
   arr[i] = i + 1;
}
```

então, embaralhe os números dentro desta array:

```
var p, n, tmp;
for (p = arr.length; p;) {
    n = Math.random() * p-- | 0;
    tmp = arr[n];
    arr[n] = arr[p];
    arr[p] = tmp;
}
```

Aí basta pegar os primeiros ítens da array, por ordem, de 1 até a quantidade de resultados que desejar, pois já estão embaralhados aleatoriamente, e nenhum se repete.

> Veja exemplo com resultados no [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/W92aL/)

<sub>resposta adaptada de https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694668/javascript-to-generate-50-no-repeat-random-numbers</sub>

### Se precisar de poucos valores:

[Esta técnica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle) é eficiente mesmo com poucos valores, basta neste caso encurtar o loop para "embaralhar" somente a quantidade necessária de números:

```
for (p = quantidade; p;) {
```

Desta forma, serão "embaralhados" apenas os primeiros valores, indicados pela variável `quantidade`.

### Sobre o algoritmo

Este algoritmo é o [Fisher-Yates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle), como reforçou o colega [@woliveirajr](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/118/woliveirajr) nos comentários, e numa outra questão, o colega [@FabriDamazio](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/73614) encontrou uma análise interessante comparando Fisher-Yates com embaralhamento força-bruta.

Vale à pena uma lida:

> [Analysis of a Brute-Force Shuffle](http://www.freefour.com/analysis-of-a-brute-force-shuffle/)

Comment: Ambas estão certos, porém, preferi o método do Sergio pelo fato deste método parecer ser mais devagar quando se quer gerar um número aleatório grande.

Comment: Esta solução é melhor que a outra porque, quando os números "livres" começarem a escassear, a outra solução vai ficar lenta (ela fica tentando outros números aleatórios até achar um desocupado).

Comment: O nome deste método é Fisher-Yates http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle

Comment: Vou deixar minha colaboração, fiz esse [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/numeros-aleatorios-sem-repeticao/1) para analisar a performance das respostas. Incluí outra opção onde é gerada um array e é removido um índice aleatório usando [`Array.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice). A resposta do Bacco é a mais performática.

Comment: @fernandosavio espero que o pessoal veja a diferença entre o ponto e a vírgula nos resultados kkk. Rodei aqui e foi "60.90" x "53,388" - Que em pt_BR seria 60,90 x 53.388,00

Answer (score 3):

Utilizo esta solução minha pela simplicidade, já que utiliza o método *sort()*, nativo da linguagem:

```
var x = new Array(1000);
for(var i=1; i<1001; i++) {
    x[i] = i; 
}

x.sort(function(a,b){ return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); });
```

Porém, o método utilizado pelo @Bacco será sempre mais rápido, já que não é necessário recriar o array.

Answer (score -1):

```js
function sorteado(max,quant) {
    var numeroS = []
    while (numeroS.length < quant) {
      e = Math.ceil(Math.random() * max);
      if (numeroS.indexOf(e) == -1) {
        numeroS.push(e)
      }
    }
   return numeroS
}
console.log(sorteado(1000,16))
```

Answer (score -2):

Ou você pode executar desta forma:

```
function getRandom(maxNum, qtdMax) {
  let n = 1;
  const lista = [];
  const val = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum + 1);
  
  do {
    while (n <= qtdMax) {
      let numero = val();

      if (lista.indexOf(numero) === -1) {
        lista.push(numero)
      } else {n -= 1};
      n += 1
    };
  } while (lista.length < qtdMax);

  lista.sort((a, b) => a - b);
  console.log(lista);
  return lista;
}

getRandom(60, 6);
```

No exemplo acima, eu deixei para rodar uma combinação aleatória de 6 dígitos (segundo parâmetro da função) com limite de valor em 60 (primeiro parâmetro da função). Assim você pode rodar a lista uma única vez para a quantidade de caracteres que você quiser e o limite do número aleatório sem fazer tantas iterações. Detalhe, coloquei um sort para organizar de forma ascendente a lista.

Em um exemplo prático, dá para buscar os dados por index no laço for, ou desestruturando:

```
const get = getRandom(60, 6);

for (const i in get) {
  const texto = `Index: ${i} = ${get[i]}`
  console.log(texto)
}

const [ num1 ] = get

console.log(num1)
```