# Sortear números sem repetir no javascript

Tags: javascript

Preciso sortear 16 número e armazená-los em um array, porém não pode haver números repetidos. Segue o código.

```js
var numero = [];

function numero_aleatorio () {
 
  for(i=0;i<16;i++) {
  
  numero.push(Math.floor((Math.random() * 16) + 1));  

 }
}

numero_aleatorio();
```

Comment: essa pergunta já tem resposta. 
 https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10282/n%C3%BAmero-aleat%C3%B3rio-sem-repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o?rq=1

Comment: Eu tentei usar aquela essa função [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10282/n%C3%BAmero-aleat%C3%B3rio-sem-repeti%C3%A7%C3%A3o?rq=1], mas não estava dando certo

Comment: Olá Diego, votei para fechar porque mesmo a resposta do Sérgio não sendo o que procura a resposta a seguir, do Bacco, responde exatamente o que precisa https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10284/3635, é sempre legal olha **além** da resposta aceita, outras respostas mesmo que não aceitas podem resolver o problema ;D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basta verificar se o número está no array antes de adicioná-lo. É necessário trocar o `for` por um `while`, já que não é possível saber ao certo quantas iterações serão necessárias para gerar 16 números diferentes:

```
var numeros = [];

function numero_aleatorio() {
    while (numeros.length < 16) {
        var aleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);

        if (numeros.indexOf(aleatorio) == -1)
            numeros.push(aleatorio);
    }
}

numero_aleatorio();
```

Note que `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` gera um número aleatório entre 0 e 99.

Comment: Valeu mesmo @rodorgas ! Só poderia me explicar essa parte do código? `if (numeros.indexOf(aleatorio) == -1)
            numeros.push(aleatorio);`

Comment: "O método indexOf() retorna o primeiro índice em que o elemento pode ser encontrado no array, retorna -1 caso o mesmo não esteja presente." -[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf). Portanto, se `numeros.indexOf` resultar `-1` para o número que acabamos de gerar, ele não está presente no array e deve ser adicionado.

Comment: Ah blz! Entendi! Valeu mesmo! :)

Comment: É nois! Você poderia usar o mais elegante `if (!numero.includes(aleatorio))`, mas como o `includes` foi introduzido no ES7 não funciona no IE.

Comment: Na verdade, `Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)` gera um número entre **0** (não 10) e 99.

Comment: Ops... Tem toda razão @Wtrmute. Atualizei a reposta, valeu.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode inserir os números de 1 a 16 dentro de um `array` e utilizar o método `sort` do `array` ordenando randomicamente com a função `Math.random())`;

```js
function _sortear(quantidade, maximo) {
  var numeros = [];

  console.time('Sorteando');

  // Preenche um array com os números de 1 ao maximo
  for (var numero = 1; numero <= maximo;  numero++) {
    numeros.push(numero);
  }
  
  numeros.sort(function randomizar(a, b) {
    return Math.random() * 2 - 1; // Ordena randomicamente
  });

  console.timeEnd('Sorteando');
  
  return numeros.splice(0, quantidade);
}

console.log(_sortear(16, 100).join(','));
```

Note que criei os parâmetros `quantidade` e `maximo`. A `quantidade` define quantos números devem ser retornados e o `maximo` define o valor máximo dos números randômicos.

Ao final da função utilizo o método `splice` para pegar as `n` primeiras posições do `array` resultante.

Answer (score -2):

Segue em exemplo simples amigo,

```
public class NumerosAleatrorios{
public static void main(String[] args){
    int numero;
    int[] num = new int[6];
    Random r = new Random();
    for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
         numero = r.nextInt(60) + 1;
         for(int j=0; j<num.length; j++){
               if(numero == num[j] && j != i){
                     numero = r.nextInt(60) + 1;
               }else{
                    num[i] = numero;
               }
         }
    }
    //Apresentar na tela o resultado
    for(int i=0; i<num.length; i++){
         System.out.print(num[i]+"  ");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Você não explicou o que está de correto no seu código nem de errado no código do AP. Também tem o fato de você ter respondido Java mas foi requerido JavaScript na questão

Comment: Então, eu precisava do código em javascript. Mas valeu pela resposta Felipe :)