# Criar botão gerador de serial number

Tags: javascript, html, formulário, button

Então, to precisando fazer um botão que gere um serial, dentro de um input text quando clicar. Mas o serial precisaria conter [wf][2017] como padrão e o restante randômico. Ex: wf2017892143.

Creio que seja com JS. Mas alguma ideia de como fazer esse botão gerando esse S/N randômico?

Comment: A parte random tem comprimento e/ou conteúdo defenido? ou pode ser qualquer caractere e qualquer comprimento?

Comment: seria apenas números, mas com minimo de 4 carcteres numericos.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Número aleatório sem repetição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10282/n%c3%bamero-aleat%c3%b3rio-sem-repeti%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O código html:

```
<input type="text" value="" id="txt_serial">
<input type="button" value="gerar" id="botao_serial">
```

Importe o jquery:

```
<scritp src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

O código utilizando o jquery:

```
function geraSerial() {
  var text = "";
  var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

  for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

  return "wf2017" + text;
}
$(function(){
    $('#botao_serial').click(function(){
        $('#txt_serial').val(geraSerial());
  });
});
```

Resultado:
https://jsfiddle.net/wictor/uqs57ugL/1/

Comment: Muito bom cara! Obrigado!

Comment: @JaiderMasterInfo só por curiosidade: marcaste esta resposta como aceite mas tinhas dito antes [quanto te perguntei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/239328/criar-bot%c3%a3o-gerador-de-serial-number/239333#comment490055_239328): _"seria apenas números"_. Mudaste de ideias? :)

Comment: @Sergio verdade, pequei neste ponto, mas é só alterar a variável 'possible' colocando apenas os números: var possible = "0123456789";

Comment: @WictorChaves nesse caso a tua resposta dá-me entre 10 a 20 duplicados em cada 5000 gerados: https://jsfiddle.net/Sergio_fiddle/qv651Lp2/

Answer (score 10):

Aqui fica uma sugestão. No minimo gera `wf20171000`, e todos os IDs são unicos.

Podias usar um ID mais complexo com [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid), que seria alfa numérico, mas para o que descreveste acho que o exemplo em baixo funciona.

```js
var geraNumeroUnico = (function() {
  var saidos = [];
  return function() {
    var numero = Math.round(Math.random() * 1e8) + 1000;
    if (saidos.includes(numero)) return geraNumeroUnico();
    saidos.push(numero);
    return numero;
  }
})();


function geraId() {
  return 'wf2017' + geraNumeroUnico();
}

// teste

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  console.log(i, geraId());
}
```

Comment: Show cara! É isso mesmo que preciso! Mas como faço pra colocar ele dentro de um determinado input!?

Comment: @JaiderMasterInfo `input.value = geraId();`

Comment: Top cara! Excelente dica! Valeu ai!

Answer (score 0):

Solução HTML/Javascript:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>

            function gerar_string_aleatoria( tam, charset )
            {
                var serial = "";

                for( var i = 0; i < tam; i++ )
                    serial += charset.charAt( Math.floor(Math.random() * charset.length) );

                return serial;
            }


            function gerar_serial()
            {
                return 'wf2017' + gerar_string_aleatoria( 6, "0123456789" );
            }

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form name='frm'>
            <input type='text' name='txtSerial' value=''>
            <input type='button' name='btnGerarSerial' onClick='document.frm.txtSerial.value = gerar_serial();'>
        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```