# Como aumentar a capacidade de processamento em Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Olá, tenho uma aplicação javascript que gerar rodadas aleatórias de um campeonato de futebol (turno e returno). Porém, para montar as rodadas em uma combinação que não repita um mesmo time na mesma rodada e dois times só podem jogar uma única vez por turno entre si, para isso usei vários loops e funções para filtrar.

Já esta funcionando perfeitamente, porém, até 16 times funciona. Quando coloco mais  do que 16 times o navegador trava(fica em espera.. e encerra). Há algum limite de processamento para o Javascript? Tem como evitar esse erro e colocar mais times?

```
  function gerarRodadas()
  {
       qtd_total_partidas = this.arrPartidas.length;
       qtd_rodadas = (this.arrTimes.length-1)*2;
       qtd_partidas_por_rodada = this.arrTimes.length/2;

       arr_pos = new Array(qtd_total_partidas); 
       iniciarArray(arr_pos, qtd_total_partidas);

       for(i=0; i<qtd_rodadas; i++)
       {   

             cond=0; //so é atualizado se for possível inserir a partida na rodada
             pos=0;

             //Completar todas as partidas por rodada
             while(cond < qtd_partidas_por_rodada)
            {
              if(pos == qtd_total_partidas)
              {
                pos=0;
              }

              if(arr_pos[pos] == 0) 
              {
                if(verificarRodada(i, this.arrRodadas, this.arrPartidas[pos]))
                {
                  if(verificarTurno(i, this.arrRodadas, this.arrPartidas[pos], qtd_rodadas/2))
                  { 
                    mandante = this.arrPartidas[pos].mandante;
                    visitante = this.arrPartidas[pos].visitante;
                    estado = this.arrPartidas[pos].estado;                  

                    res1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);
                    res2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6);

                    rodDupla = verificarRodadaDupla(i, estado, this.arrRodadas);

                    this.arrRodadas.push({rodada:i, mandante: mandante, visitante:visitante, estado: estado, resMandante: res1, resVisitante: res2, rodadaDupla: rodDupla});
                    arr_pos[pos] = 1;    
                    cond++;
                  }
                 }
               }
               pos++;
             }
        }

  }
```

Comment: Ou não está claro o que quer ou já tem perguntas sobre o assunto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/10282/101 Quase todos problemas de performance se resolvem estudando algoritmos e estrutura de dados. Minha definição de perfeitamente é diferente, perfeito não tem problemas, o que dá problema não é perfeito. Em 99,999% das vezes o problema não é a tecnologia usada e sim o código da pessoa.

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56836/defini%c3%a7%c3%a3o-da-nota%c3%a7%c3%a3o-big-o