# Gerar 7 dezenas aleatórias usando javascript e loop for? Como fazer?

Tags: javascript, array, funções, for

Esse é o meu código:

```js
function gerarDezenas() {

   var dezenas = ["d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6"];

   for (var i = 0; i < dezenas.length; i++) {

                 Math.random()*60
   dezenas[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 60 +1); // isso é correto?

    console.log(dezenas) ou return... (??);
}
  
}
```

não consegui imprimir nada.

também não consigo entender quando um código precisa ter return ou não.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Gerar vários números aleatórios sem repetição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10282/gerar-v%c3%a1rios-n%c3%bameros-aleat%c3%b3rios-sem-repeti%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Segue o código funcional.

```js
gerarDezenas();

function gerarDezenas() {
   var dezenas = ["d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6"];

   for (var i = 0; i < dezenas.length; i++) {
        Math.random()*60
        dezenas[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
        console.log(dezenas[i]);
    }
}
```

No caso, o return serve pra quando vc quer ter o retorno da função, para salvar em alguma variável, e utilizar mais tarde.:

```js
 console.log(gerarDezenas());

    function gerarDezenas() {
       var dezenas = ["d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6"];

       for (var i = 0; i < dezenas.length; i++) {
            Math.random()*60
            dezenas[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 60 + 1);
        }
        return dezenas;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Provavelmente seria melhor escrever assim:
(estou presumindo que você quer gerar dezenas como num jogo de loteria)

```
function gerarDezenas(numDezenas) {
    var dezenas = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numDezenas; i++) {
        dezenas[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
    }
    return dezenas;
}
console.log(gerarDezenas(7));
```

#### O que foi modificado?

- O número de dezenas passou a ser um parâmetro da função e não um tamanho "hardcoded" dentro dela. *(Isso ainda traz benefícios de performance em baixo nível pois o tipo do array não muda, mas isso é outra conversa.)*
- removi a expressão `Math.random()*60` que estava sozinha ali, exigindo processamento, mas sem fazer nenhuma contribuição ao seu algorítmo.
- Multipliquei o `random` por 100 para ter dezenas acima de `60` porque acredito que o certo é ter todas as dezenas. Se não volte para 60.
- Usei `floor` em vez de `round` para ter números entre `0` e `99` com
  igual probabilidade, em vez de `0` a `100` onde os extremos tem a
  metade da probabilidade de qq outro número. Leia a definição desses
  métodos e você dirá "Sim! Claro!"
- Removi o `+1` para pegar o `0`. Se vc quiser de `1` a `100`, coloque-o de volta. (Não entendo de jogatina)
- Tirei o `console.log()` da função para que ela possa ser usada em outros fins, não apenas gerar e printar no console. Essa é uma boa prática. Funções devem se ater a uma ação especifica.
- Coloquei o `return` para que essa função seja capaz de entregar o resultado do seu trabalho à outras funções para diversos fins, os quais essa função não precisa e nem deve saber.
- Fora da função eu fiz o log, já passando a saída da função geradora como argumento deste log. A idéia é exatamente a mesma das aulas de mátemática que você teve no ensino médio "GoF de x" = "g(f(x))"

---

Ainda existe um porém: é possível que o array retornado pela função tenha números repetidos. Mas isso já é outra conversa...

Answer (score 1):

Em algum lugar do seu código você invocou a função `gerarDezenas()`? Para o comportamento de uma função ser executado, é necessário que você a invoque. Para isso escrevemos o nome da função e um par de parênteses no final.

```js
// Invocando função
gerarDezenas();
```

Outra dica é sobre a indentação. Sempre que você abrir chaves, lembre-se de indentar o código que está dentro das chaves em mais um nível. Ou seja, quando você declarar uma função, uma condicional, um laço... conforme você for abrindo novas estruturas você indenta mais, melhorando a compreensão. Fica mais fácil de ver que aquele bloco pertence àquela estrutura. Seu código com a indentação correta ficaria assim:

```js
function gerarDezenas() {

   var dezenas = ["d1","d2","d3","d4","d5","d6"];

   for (var i = 0; i < dezenas.length; i++) {
       dezenas[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 60 +1); // isso é correto?
       console.log(dezenas);
   }
}
```

Agora sobre o código em si. A função `Math.random()` gera um número entre 0 e 1, exclusivo no 1, isto é, até 0.9999... (infinitos noves). Então se você pega isso e multiplica por 60, você vai ter um número entre 0 e 59.9999... Se você utilizar somente o `Math.round()` em cima disso, sem aquele +1, isso geraria um número entre 0 e 60. Como você somou 1, resultaria entre 1 e 61.

Além disso, note que você está fazendo
`console.log(dezenas)`

Isso vai printar a sua lista de dezenas inteira, terá a seguinte saída:
`['d1', 'd2', ..., 'd6' ]`

Acredito que o que você queria fazer era printar o i-ésimo elemento da lista de dezenas, isto é,
`console.log(dezenas[i])`

Que printará uma string diferente a cada iteração do laço.

Por fim, uma função ter retorno ou não (função void) depende do tipo de comportamento que você espera dela. Se você quer que a função produza algum resultado, certamente ela terá retorno. Se você só deseja que ela realize uma ação, ou cause um efeito colateral, ela vai ser void. A sua função por exemplo, poderia ser feita das duas formas:

- Retornando uma lista de dezenas aleatórias.
- Imprimindo uma lista de dezenas aleatórias.

Answer (score 0):

Gerar 7 dezenas aleatórias usando javascript e loop for? Como fazer?

```js
//numero de dezenas
const ARRAY_7DEZENAS = 7;
const randomArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i<ARRAY_7DEZENAS; i++) {randomArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * 100))};

    //separados por traço
    console.log(randomArray.join( '-' ));
    //array
    console.log(randomArray);
```

Se quiser gerar 7 números **aleatórios únicos** em javascript você precisa criar um objeto, neste caso, você pode usar uma matriz, que contém todos os números possíveis que podem aparecer, chamado n. Em seguida, você pode usar um loop while para continuar escolhendo números dessa matriz e adicionando pelo metodo push() e removendo pelo metodo splice() esse número específico da matriz em cada iteração. Vai entender melhor observando os comentários no código.

```js
function gerarDezenas() {
  // para armazenar as 7 dezenas 
  var escolha = [];
  
  //para armazenar todas as dezenas de 0 a n
  var arrayNumeros = [];

  // n é o valor máximo que pode aparecer entre os 7 numeros
  n=100;
  
  for ( var i = 0; i < n; i++ ) { 
    // Armazenando os numeros de 0 a 100
    arrayNumeros.push(i);
  }

  while (escolha.length < 7){
     var indiceAleatorio = Math.floor(Math.random() * arrayNumeros.length);
     
     //adicionando um numero no array escolha a ser apresentado
     escolha.push(arrayNumeros[indiceAleatorio]);
     
     // retirando o numero do array
     arrayNumeros.splice(indiceAleatorio, 1);
  }

  console.log(escolha);
}
gerarDezenas();
```