# Retornar um array de 6 números aleatórios entre 01 a 60

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando criar **números aleatórias (01 a 60) com 6 digitos**

```
 const valor = n => {
     var add = 1, max = 12 - add;
     if ( n > max ) {
     return valor(max) + valor(n - max);
     }
     max = Math.pow(10, n+add);
     var min = max/10; 
     var number = Math.floor( Math.random() *  (max - min + 1) ) + min;
     return ("" + number).substring(add);
     }
```

Não sei o que fazer ai...

ja tentei colocar o `var number = Math.floor( Math.random() * 60 (max - min + 1) ) + min;` mas da um erro...

Comment: Seu código está gerando uma string com n dígitos randômicos perfeitamente.

Não entendi bem qual o seu objetivo. "6 dígitos" é a quantidade de dígitos que você pode usar para gerar o número? Se for o caso, quais dígitos podem ser utilizados?
Se não for, tente exclarecer melhor a questão.

Comment: Numero aleatórias está tudo certo ai , mas eu quero exemplo assim quando eu colocar valor(6) é numero aleatórias com 6 digitos certo? ( 12, 92, 76, 65, 23, 99) mas eu n quero pegar o maximo de 60 e minimo 01 entendeu?

Comment: Você quer números aleatórios entre 1 e 60, é isso??

Comment: simm , não em um so numero, é com 6... (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

Comment: Você quer 6 números de 1 a 60? Tipo: [12, 59, 41, 20, 30, 44]?

Comment: Sim, isso que eu quero!

Comment: Só lembrando que a resposta abaixo pode gerar números repetidos (não ficou claro se podia ter repetidos ou não, mas enfim, fica o alerta). Se quiser garantir que não haja repetição, veja aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/10284/112052

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A função numeroAleatorio abaixo gera um número aleatório entre min e max.
A função gerarNumerosEntre1a60 vai gerar um array com n números aleatórios do intervalo de [1,60].

```
const numeroAleatorio = (min, max) => {
    return Math.floor( Math.random() *  (max - min + 1) ) + min;
};

const gerarNumerosEntre1a60 = n => {
    const resultado = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
       resultado.push(numeroAleatorio(1,60));
    }
    return resultado;
}

// Para gerar 6 números:
console.log(gerarNumerosDe1a60(6));
```

Comment: Muito obrigado fera!