# Mostrar resultado de um array aleatório!

Tags: javascript, array, random

Boa noite! Sou novato em Javascript. Fiz um estudo tipo memorização de palavras onde pego um determinado número de palavras dentro de um Array. As palavras são aleatórias e mostradas uma a uma. Mas gostaria de implementar um botão pra mostrar todas as palavras que foram escolhidas em uma lista, como uma resposta pra conferir depois. Alguém pode me dar um caminho? Obrigado.

```
o index:

 <div id="container">
    <h1>Random</h1>

    <div id="random"></div>

    <select  id="palavras"> 
        <option value="10"  selected>10 palavras</option>
        <option value="20" >20 palavras</option>
        <option value="30">30 palavras</option>
    </select>


    <button id="iniciar" >Iniciar</button>
    <button id="resposta" style=" display: none;">Resposta</button>


    <select  id="tempo"> 
        <option value="1000"  selected>1 segundo</option>
        <option value="2000" >2 segundos</option>
        <option value="5000">5 segundos</option>
    </select>

   <div id="lista" style=" display: none; margin-top: 50px;"> 
 
</div>


O script.js

 let random = document.getElementById('random');
 let resposta = document.getElementById('resposta');
 let tempo = document.getElementById('tempo');
 let palavras = document.getElementById('palavras');
 let inicar= document.getElementById('iniciar');



function randomWords(min, max){
   let step1 = max - min +1;
   let step2 = Math.random() * step1;
   let result = Math.floor(step2) + min;
   return result;
}

let words =  [
 
  'Barriga',
  'Bicicleta',
  'Formiga',
  'Garrafa',
  'Teclado',
  'Mouse',
  'Caneca',
  'Cerveja',
  'Barata',
  'Cigarro',
  'Café',
  'Copo',
  'Poste',
  'Bola',
  'Balão',
  'Igreja',
  'Padre',
  'Carro',
  'Caminhão',
  'Monitor',
 
];



function verificaDez(){
  if(words.length == 20){
    random.innerText = "Clique em resposta par ver o resultado"; 
    document.getElementById('resposta').style.display = "block";   
     return;       
 }    
 let randomIndex = randomWords (0,words.length-1) ;
 let randomWord = words[randomIndex];   
 words.splice(randomIndex,1);      
 random.innerText = randomWord;  

}


function verificaVinte(){
  if(words.length == 10){
    random.innerText = "Clique no botão resposta para ver o resultado"; 
    document.getElementById('resposta').style.display = "block";   
     return;       
 }    
 let randomIndex = randomWords (0,words.length-1) ;
 let randomWord = words[randomIndex];   
 words.splice(randomIndex,1);      
 random.innerText = randomWord;  

}

function verificaTrinta(){
  if(words.length == 0){
    random.innerText = "Clique em resposta par ver o resultado"; 
    document.getElementById('resposta').style.display = "block";   
     return;       
 }    
 let randomIndex = randomWords (0,words.length-1) ;
 let randomWord = words[randomIndex];   
 words.splice(randomIndex,1);      
 random.innerText = randomWord;  

}

iniciar.addEventListener("click", function( ) {
  if(palavras.value == 10){
    setInterval(verificaDez, tempo.value);
  }else if ( palavras.value == 20){
    setInterval(verificaVinte, tempo.value);
  }else if( palavras.value == 30){
    setInterval(verificaTrinta, tempo.value);
  } 
}
);


resposta.addEventListener("click", function( ) { 
  
}
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wnobre/epzLm05r/  " Exemplo de como ficou"

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Gerar vários números aleatórios sem repetição](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10282/gerar-v%c3%a1rios-n%c3%bameros-aleat%c3%b3rios-sem-repeti%c3%a7%c3%a3o)

Comment: @RafaelTavares Na verdade eu já consegui gerar as palavras aleatórias! O que eu não consegui foi depois de mostrar as palavras aleatórias , recuperar e mostrar todas de uma vez numa lista. Não sei se deu pra entender, rs

Comment: Você diz na resposta? Seu evento click de resposta a função está vazia...

Comment: @MagicHat Sim! Tá vazia, pq não sei como retornar essas palavras que foram mostradas aleatoriamente. É justamente essa a minha dúvida.

Comment: Hum, entendi... E nem tentou nada?

Comment: @MagicHat Tentei tudo que sabia, rs! Mas, sou iniciante e nada deu certo.

Comment: Então, o ideal é colocar o código que tentou...

Answer (score 2):

Siga os seguintes passos:

1. Crie uma variável dentro do escopo global contendo um array vazio.

```
const displayedWords = [];
```

2. Substitua `words.splice(randomIndex,1))` dentro de suas funções "verifica" pelo seguinte código, que adicionará cada palavra sorteada ao array criado anteriormente:

```
displayedWords.push(words.splice(randomIndex,1)[0]);
```

3. Preencha a função chamada ao clicar em "Resposta" com este código, que irá adicionar uma lista contendo as palavras sorteadas ao seu HTML:

```
  const list = document.createElement('ul');
  list.style.paddingLeft = '0';
  displayedWords.forEach((word) => {
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${word}</li>`);
  });
  document.querySelector('#container').insertBefore(list, random);
  displayedWords.length = 0;
```

O código complete ficaria assim:

```js
let random = document.getElementById('random');
 let resposta = document.getElementById('resposta');
 let tempo = document.getElementById('tempo');
 let palavras = document.getElementById('palavras');
 let lista = document.getElementById('lista');
 let inicar= document.getElementById('iniciar');



function randomWords(min, max){
   let step1 = max - min +1;
   let step2 = Math.random() * step1;
   let result = Math.floor(step2) + min;
   return result;
}

let words =  [
 
  'Barriga',
  'Bicicleta',
  'Formiga',
  'Garrafa',
  'Teclado',
  'Mouse',
  'Caneca',
  'Cerveja',
  'Barata',
  'Cigarro',
  'Café',
  'Copo',
  'Poste',
  'Bola',
  'Balão',
  'Igreja',
  'Padre',
  'Carro',
  'Caminhão',
  'Monitor',
  '1',
  '2',
  '3',
  '4',
  '5',
  '6',
  '7',
  '8',
  '9',
  '10',
 

];

const displayedWords = [];


function verificaDez(){
  if(words.length == 20){
    random.innerText = "Clique em resposta par ver o resultado"; 
    document.getElementById('resposta').style.display = "block";   
     return;       
 }    
 let randomIndex = randomWords (0,words.length-1) ;
 let randomWord = words[randomIndex];   
 displayedWords.push(words.splice(randomIndex,1)[0]);      
 random.innerText = randomWord;  

}


function verificaVinte(){
  if(words.length == 10){
    random.innerText = "Clique no botão resposta para ver o resultado"; 
    document.getElementById('resposta').style.display = "block";   
     return;       
 }    
 let randomIndex = randomWords (0,words.length-1) ;
 let randomWord = words[randomIndex];   
 displayedWords.push(words.splice(randomIndex,1)[0]);         
 random.innerText = randomWord;  

}

function verificaTrinta(){
  if(words.length == 0){
    random.innerText = "Clique em resposta par ver o resultado"; 
    document.getElementById('resposta').style.display = "block";   
     return;       
 }    
 let randomIndex = randomWords (0,words.length-1) ;
 let randomWord = words[randomIndex]; 
 displayedWords.push(words.splice(randomIndex,1)[0]);       
 random.innerText = randomWord;  

}

iniciar.addEventListener("click", function( ) {
  if(palavras.value == 10){
    setInterval(verificaDez, tempo.value);
  }else if ( palavras.value == 20){
    setInterval(verificaVinte, tempo.value);
  }else if( palavras.value == 30){
    setInterval(verificaTrinta, tempo.value);
  } 
}
);


resposta.addEventListener("click", function( ) { 
  const list = document.createElement('ul');
  list.style.paddingLeft = '0';
  displayedWords.forEach((word) => {
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<li>${word}</li>`);
    });
  document.querySelector('#container').insertBefore(list, random);
  displayedWords.length = 0;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Random</title>
<style>

    body{
        margin: 0, auto;
    }
    #random {
      margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
  
    #tempo {
        margin-top: 20px;      
    }
    input{
        width: 20px;
    }
    ul{
        list-style: none;
    }

    
</style>

</head>
<body>
    <center>
   <div id="container">
    <h1>Random</h1>

    <div id="random"></div>

    <select  id="palavras"> 
        <option value="10"  selected>10 palavras</option>
        <option value="20" >20 palavras</option>
        <option value="30">30 palavras</option>
    </select>


    <button id="iniciar" >Iniciar</button>
    <button id="resposta" style=" display: none;">Resposta</button>


    <select  id="tempo"> 
        <option value="1000"  selected>1 segundo</option>
        <option value="2000" >2 segundos</option>
        <option value="5000">5 segundos</option>
    </select>

   <div id="lista" style=" display: none; margin-top: 50px;"> 
 
</div>
  
    
</div>
</center> 

  <script src="script.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Dica: junte suas funções "verifica" em uma só, passando dados variáveis por parâmetro.

Comment: Cara! Exatamente isso que eu precisava. Valeu mesmo. Sobre a sua dica, vou dar uma estudada. Obrigado!